# Dynamic Response in Twilio with Node (Wait for response)

Tags: node.js, express, post, twilio

I am currently trying to build a **Twilio SMS** app that responds to incoming sms message based on their previous message using conditional statements.

My app gets a request and post a respond.

I want the app to wait for a respond and continue from the next if statement but instead it just runs from the top, and checks the first if statement all over again.

The purpose is i want to treat it like a chat and a real conversation and hold data and context from previous message not only the message before.

**Example:**

```
app.post('/sms', (req,res) => {
const twiml = new messageResponse();
let textData = req.body.Body // Incoming SMS Body

 if(textData === "Hello") {
     twiml.message('Hello! Thanks for reaching out');
 };

 //Step 2: wait for next incoming message
if(textData === "Order Status") {
    twiml.message(`Your order status is ${order.status}`)
}
```

I want the app to wait for a response and pick up from "Step 2" rather than running the entire post again?

**What I've Tried**
- I tried creating functions and running those functions using the If statements returning values. Example:

```
app.post('/sms', (req,res) => {
    const twiml = new messageResponse();
    let textData = req.body.Body // Incoming SMS Body
    let userGreet = false

    let replyBack = () => {
        if (textData.includes('hello')) {
            return userGreet = true;
        } 
    }

    userGreet = replyBackBack()

     if(userGreet) {
         twiml.message('Hello! Thanks for reaching out');
     };

     //Step 2: wait for next incoming message
    if(textData === "Order Status") {
        twiml.message(`Your order status is ${order.status}`)
    }

}
```

Is this even possible?
All help and suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you respond to incoming messages like that, you are actually returning a response to the incoming HTTP request. The response is XML ([TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms)) and methods like `twiml.message` build up that response. You need to return the result and end the function in order to make the reply. Therefore you can't wait for the next response within the function.

What you can do though, is store the conversation that you have had so far in a cookie, which is then sent back with the next webhook from the next message. I could describe all that in this answer, but instead, I recommend this tutorial on [building an SMS conversation with Twilio and Node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-node-js) which walks you through a full example of how to achieve this.